# What is the law on CBD oil brought into Mexico from Canadian visitors?

Tags: canada, borders, mexico, canadian-citizens

I learned that medical use of marihuana is legal in Mexico since 2017 but there's little information on regulations for the use of the oil as a visitor.

It looks like the Mexican Government has approved individual permits to Mexican nationals for medical uses.

Can a Canadian national travel with the oil if it's prescribed by a registered Canadian physician?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn’t risk it given the current variance in national laws. Imagine if your plane develops a problem and you have to land in the USA.

I’m sure you can find cbd oils in Mexico too.

Comment: Is that actually an issue? For example, it wouldn't be a problem if a flight was diverted to the US and there were passengers on board who needed US visas but didn't have them. Would a passenger arriving in these circumstances even pass through immigration and customs?

Comment: The moment they landed they would be subject to US law and marijuana related products are still illegal at the federal level. Just ask the numerous people who have accidentally taken the wrong exit at Detroit, ended up going to Canada, turning right around and ended up going through American customs and immigration and having their cars tossed and then arrested on minor smuggling charges.